# Abandoned instances that will not continue execution (zombie instances)

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I have a lot of WF instances hosted in IIS/WAS which are in a running (idle) state which will not do anything even though they don't have such a long delay or any active bookmark.

Tracking is enabled (HealthMonitoringProfile).

As the tracking data is deleted, they end up without any tracked instance or events.

The only way to make them work again is to suspend and resume them, but this is sometimes failing and is always a pain.

Has anyone had this issue? any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any clue on why the zombie instance exist in the first place? What is your unhanded exception setting in AppFabric?

Comment: It's set to Abandon. I'm thinking it could be some version mismatch, but I can't see anything on traces about it

Answer (score 0):

In that case they are most likely triggering an error and abort leaving their state. As there is no trigger for them to start executing they just sit there and do nothing. The default option is to AbandonAndSuspend so you can resume them. You need to figure out what is causing them to fault and normally you can see that in the traced information.

Comment: Isn't the WMS supposed to take aborted instances as candidates for running? I have seen instances that aborted by some error (i.e.: a service not available at that moment) and they continued their execution.

Comment: I'm thinking of some "hidden" errors. I have posted a possible bug in connect that may be related. https://connect.microsoft.com/wf/feedback/details/667934/system-runtime-serialization-serializationexception-when-resuming-a-wf-instance-hosted-in-iis

Comment: I have also seen this problem in instances belonging to services with the AbandonAndSuspend option. The problem is that I don't know how to reproduce the issue.