# AppFabric / WF 4.0 instances stuck despite no bookmark and pending timer

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I already posted a question about this ([Abandoned instances that will not continue execution (zombie instances)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961629/abandoned-instances-that-will-not-continue-execution-zombie-instances)), but still haven't got an answer.

A difference I have noticed from the last question is that it can happen also when the configuration of the service Action on unhandled exception is set AbandonAndSuspend.

So the scenario is a long term Workflow service hosted in IIS using AppFabric persistence store. This service performs some actions and then polls the result from a database. This polling is done every 30 minutes. For some reason the WF gets stuck and doesn't do anything else. Checking the InstancesTable I can see a past pending timer and an old LastUpdateTime.

The only workaround I found is to suspend and then resume the instances, which is obviously a painful process (there are around 5000 instances in this situation).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do they resume normal operations after a suspend & resume operation?

Comment: I forgot to ask: Are you seeing any errors in the tracked event now?

Comment: Hello, yes, they resume normal operations. Tracked events are removed after a while, so I cannot see, but if there were the instance would be suspended I guess.

Comment: I think the issue might be related with the throttling and runnable instances detection period configuration. Would it be possible that the WMS would only take the max concurrent instances number and, if the period is long enough, it wouldn't have time to really pick all of them?

Comment: @Dortró: Throttling limits don't suspend workflows, it just keeps them in the queue for execution longer. You are really going to need to change your tracking to keep events for longer because guessing why they are suspended is not going to get you very far.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. The WFs are not being suspended. What I was wondering is whether due to the combination of the amount of instances, a high runnable detection period and a low number of concurrent instances, there are sets of instances that shall never come to life

Comment: How do you know they never come to life if you don't have any tracking that tells you what is or isn't happening?

Comment: Because the last persisted time is from days ago

Comment: Did you consider the posibility that it might have come to life and something went wrong causing the WSH to ignore the instances?

Comment: I solved it!

The problem, as suspected, was related to the maximum number of concurrent instances. Due to some technical problems in a WCF that might be unavailable, there were a number of instances continuously running (retrying a call to that WCF) that were coping that number of maximum concurrent instances. Due to that, there were very few instances activated on every detection period.

Thanks Maurice for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as suspected, was related to the maximum number of concurrent instances. Due to some technical problems in a WCF that might be unavailable, there were a number of instances continuously running (retrying a call to that WCF) that were coping that number of maximum concurrent instances. Due to that, there were very few instances activated on every detection period. Thanks Maurice for your help